# Elastic search dynamic_templates of not_analyzed index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, mapping

I am trying to create a mapping for one of my index in Elastic Search. 
For most of the elements of my documents the dynamic mapping is good enough. But for each key inside my dimensions object I need to have a not_analyzed index.

Exemple of one document :

```
{"key1":"value1",
"dimensions":   {"563a92a1b7f2b700196bd3cd":"G1",
                  "43214b7f2b700196bd3432":4321}}
```

In that case I want key1 to be dynamically mapped but both my dimensions not_analyzed. The trick is that I don't know the key of the dimensions in advance. So I am using dynamic template.

What I have so far:

```
{
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "dimensions": {
          "match": "dimensions.*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But it is not working. 
Any idea?

thanks

Comment: What is not working? Can you show us what you get when seeing the generated mapping `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping`

Comment: Sorry about that: When I do a search on a dimensions using a value with two or less char it doesn't return anything. For exemple:
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { "query": {
        "bool": { "must":{
              "term": {
                "dimensions.5632ede91c305c001ab3905f": "G1"
              }
            }}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to use the [`path_match` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) instead of the `match` one when trying to match the name of a field within another object. So your dynamic template should look like this:

```
{
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "dimensions": {
          "path_match": "dimensions.*",           <--- fix this line
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```